# PHP sqlsrv_execute re-execute a prepared statement several times

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I was reading [`sqlsrv_execute` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php) and found the interesting "Example #1" which shows how to re-execute a statement several times.

My problem is that I have more than 2 parameters in my query. How do I pass them to the `sqlsrv_execute` cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the documentation is just that, *an example*. It is showing you how you *could* loop through an array that has key-value pairs and insert them as individual rows into the database; but it doesn't mean that it is the only way to do it.

Let's do a simple example with a few parameters:

---

Let's say we are importing into our database multiple entries of customer details which include: `name`, `gender`, `dob` and `address`. Typically we would get these in array form from a `<form>` through either a `POST` or `GET` request. So, for example, we could have the following arrays:

```
// Names             // Genders        // DoB                     // Address
Array (              Array (           Array (                    Array (
    [0] => "Bob"         [0] => "M"        [0] => "25/04/1994"        [0] => "123 Somewhere Lane"
    [1] => "Tim"         [1] => "M"        [1] => "02/12/1986"        [1] => "456 Somewhere Lane"
    [2] => "Jane"        [2] => "F"        [2] => "29/06/2001"        [2] => "789 Somewhere Lane"
)                    )                 )                          )
```

Now lets create our prepared statement:

```
//We've already got a connection created

$query = "INSERT INTO [customers].[cust_details] 
          ([name], [gender], [DoB], [address])
          VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array(&$name, &$gender, &$dob, &$address));
```

The variables `$name`, `$gender`, `$dob` and `$address` are now bound to this statement.

Now let's create a loop to execute the query multiple times:

```
// I used a for loop here as an example
// but choose whatever loop is suitable for what you need to achieve

for($i = 0; $i < count($namesArray); $i++) {
    // Each iteration will store a different value into these variables
    // These variables are bound to $stmt, therefore whatever is stored
    // at the time of sqlsrv_execute() is sent as the parameters
    $name    = $namesArray[$i];
    $gender  = $gendersArray[$i];
    $dob     = $dobsArray[$i];
    $address = $addressesArray[$i];

    // Execute the statement
    if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false) { 
        // there has been an error
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```

**Note:** `sqlsrv_execute()` returns a `boolean` result as to whether the query was successful or not. To access the resource you would use `$stmt`.